# Conditional use of value from Global resources in labels

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class TypeOfCalc that has a property (bool) where base on that I can now how to do calculations (example true for Millions or false for Thousands) and then this return corrected result.

The problem is that I need somehow to bind (set) the label text so at runtime when the TypeOfCalc has property true then labels should display example:

**Calc (Mil):**

else if TypeOfCalc has property false then this label should be:

**Calc (TSD):**

(image this has to be set in all forms that I have to many of them)
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind you could do something like this.

```
myLabel.text = TypeOfCalc.property == true ? "Calc (Mil):" : "Calc (TSD):";
```

Comment: Yes this is Ok if I have one label to 10 but this I have more then 100 of theme and they are in different webforms.